# Google Scholar has lumped two publications into one

Tags: publications, google-scholar

How do I correct a google scholar error or omission or duplication?

Comment: Contact them, they should have a help point.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. We have many questions on Google Scholar that are not considered off-topic. What makes this one different? https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google+scholar

Answer (score 9):

**You can edit it manually.**

If you log in to your profile, there are several options to combine/separate articles.  You can also edit specific article details: click on the article title, then click on the pen icon in the top-right:
[image]